# Joomla ssl problem

Tags: apache, ssl, joomla

I have a site on joomla and I want to make some specific pages works by secure connection ,
other by simple http connection. Is there some step-by-step manual how to setup apache and joomla for such needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create a two Apache configuration for this site. One for port 80 (http), and the other for 443 (https). In the settings menu in the admin panel to specify "ssl enabled" to the desired value.

Comment: I noticed that home page always skip sll settings of menu item. To fix this I added live_site value to cinfiguration.php with scheme hardcoded (https)

Answer (score 0):

There's a Joomla Plugin called SSL Redirect plugin by Yireo software that might simplify the setup if some parts of the site are SSL and some not.

http://joomlawebhosting.ca/joomla-15-tips/63-joomla-ssl-https-setup.html

---

http://www.joomlahackers.net/joomla-tutorials/how-to-setup-ssl-in-a-joomla-site.html

http://www.joomlahackers.net/virtuemart-tutorials/how-to-setup-ssl-in-virtuemart-in-a-joomla-site.html